# Different behaviors for dplyr versus plyr summarize() when "reusing" a variable in the summarize() call

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I was unable to find documentation why the following difference in behavior occurs when comparing a `summarize()` call from `dplyr` with the same call using `plyr`. The difference boils down to that `dplyr`'s `summarize()` immediately reuses a variable (not sure whether reusing is the proper idiom) whereas `plyr`'s version acts more like the conceptual model that (at least) I have of its function(ing).

```
(dfr <- data.frame(a=gl(3,3, labels=letters[1:3]), b=c(1:3, rep(NA_integer_, 3), 1:2, NA_integer_)))
ddply(dfr, .(a), summarize, b=mean(b, na.rm=TRUE), s=sd(b, na.rm=TRUE))
  a   b         s
1 a 2.0 1.1547005
2 b NaN 0.0000000
3 c 1.5 0.8660254
```

This is as I expected it: the `ddply()` basically says take `dfr` in sections indicated by `a` and then compute first the mean and then the sd of a specific variable.

However, when I use dplyr instead, I get this:

```
dfr %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(b=mean(b, na.rm=TRUE), s=sd(b, na.rm=TRUE))
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  a   b   s
1 a 2.0 NaN
2 b NaN NaN
3 c 1.5 NaN
```

So this says take `dfr` in chunks indicated by `a` and then first compute the mean of a variable `b` and then use that mean to compute an sd (i.e., `s` actually is `sd(mean(b))`).

I was unable to find a hint how/why this differences between the two plyr packages exists. And, indeed, the coding style of the above call is rather suboptimal and the below code works as it should be. Nevertheless, in my view the workings of `summarize()` between the two packages is sufficiently dissimilar to warrant a clear indication somewhere in the help pages.

```
dfr %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(m=mean(b, na.rm=TRUE), s=sd(b, na.rm=TRUE))
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  a   m         s
1 a 2.0 1.0000000
2 b NaN       NaN
3 c 1.5 0.7071068
```

Comment: Actually, only now that I am re-reading my post I see that the `ddply` call gives wrong sd's as a results. So even there something fishy is going on with my call to `summarize`. Now it is actually the case that it is unfortunate that is not as clearly visible that something's wrong as it is in the dplyr version.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `dplyr` reuses variables. As a result your initial code is trying to calculate a standard deviation from just one value. When you look at the formula for the standard deviation:

[image]

you can see that the denominator of the formula will have a `0`, which causes the `NaN` result.

In your second `dplyr` code, the standard devation is calculated from the original variable. As the groups for which a `sd` is calculated have `n > 1`, the denominator in this case is larger than zero which will result in a `sd` value.

`dplyr` just takes the last created instance of a variable. In the page @baptiste linked to, you can find [this statement of Hadley Wickham](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/196#issuecomment-34274479) from which you can conclude that it's better to use new names when creating new variables.

I think this behavior should be stated explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Jaap, yeah, that's clear (now). The thing is, I couldn't find anywhere _that_ `dplyr` is reusing the variables.

Comment: I agree it should be documented more clearly than in the issues queue for the code.